# How to retrieve all rows from Data Extension using WSProxy

Tags: marketing-cloud, wsproxy

I need to retrieve all rows from a data extension to create a validateEmail API call. There are almost 400 000 users in the data extension, so I need to use WSProxy, because it allows to retrieve more than 2500 rows.

It doesn't work when I try to retrieve data extension.

```
<script runat='server'>
Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");
var config = {
           name: "VegetarianDE" (this is the name of my data extension within contact builder)
           cols: ["SubscriberKey, "EmailAddress"] (I have 2 fields in this data extension)
}
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var data = prox.retrieve("DataExtensionObject[" + config.name + "]", config.cols);

Write("first row in retrieved data is " + data.results[0].EmailAddress) 

</script>
```

I receive 'first row in retrieved data is undefined'.

Comment: You can't reference the WSProxy retrieve results like that.  I'd suggest reviewing the "Format the results" section on Ivan Razine's blog post on this topic: https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-retrieve-more-than-2500-records-from-a-data-extension-with-server-side-javascript/

Comment: `results[0]` needs to be capitalized. `Results[0]`. JS is case sensitive unlike AMPscript.